# Google Maps API v3: Fit map to markers while keeping center point fixed

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have the following code to add a list of Marker's to my Map and auto-fit the bounds:

```
var fitToMarkers = function(markers) {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var length = markers.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng));
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
};
```

But what I really want to do is to first center the map on another Marker or LatLng object, THEN add a list of markers to the map and have the map automatically zoom out (while keeping the original center point) until it fits the whole list of markers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

bounds.extend is doing most of the work for you. Once all your markers have been added you'll have a LatLngBounds that encompasses all of your points. You'll be able to use getNorthEast() and getSouthWest() to get the corners for this box. With your original center you should be able to calculate the following

1) The furthest point from the center along the x axis 
2) The furthest point from the center along the y axis

If you reflect these values along your original center you should wind up with values you can use to construct a new LatLngBounds.

map.fitBounds on thee bounds should accomplish what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not very efficient, but ...

You could recursively zoom out checking if the Lat long is with in the map bounds each time

```
// keep zooming out until map contains cords 
function zoomOut(bounds, latlng, currentZoom) {
    if (!bounds.contains(latlng)) {
        var newZoom = currentZoom - 1;
        map.setZoom(newZoom);
        zoomOut(map.getBounds(), latlng, newZoom);
    }   
}

var fitToMarkers = function(markers) {
    var length = markers.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
         var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng)
         zoomOut(map.getBounds(), latlng, map.getZoom());
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up doing and it works fine for a quick fix, especially since in my use-case this is more of a graceful failure. I did have to wrap this in a ```google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {``` to get the bounds to be defined, FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng);
```

requires an extra ')' at the end:

```
bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng));
```

Comment: Be more descriptive and specific to OP's question. Please read:[How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).